# Having trouble wrapping my head around こういうの in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-order

> クリスマス… 悪くはないわね、こういうの。提督、私は好きよ。少し…酔いそう。

I can understand pretty much everything but the use of こういうの in there, is there something I'm missing? Is the speaker just reinforcing the statement they've said before? I'm not sure how or why こういうの is there or what it adds to the sentence.

Comment: Hi, just to understand more this question - are they doing something unexpected or special things? What are they doing?

Answer (score 3):

I think the word order is reversed in the first sentence (in that the predicate is placed in front of its arguments).

In the normal order the sentence would be:

> こういうのは悪くない

That leaves us with クリスマス, and this part doesn't seem well connected to the rest of the sentence. One way to think about it is an apposition with こういうの. Another is to think it as a separate, one-word sentence that just observes that "[I see that] it's Christmas."